# Coldfusion Error and IIS7.5 Error Pages

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5

In order to allows ColdFusion showing its errors instead of just server error (code 500), I have added  to web.config according to some findings in this site.

The problem looks resolved but...

When I visit a non-existed directory in the IIS, it returned a "blank" page without any status code. If I set it from passthrough back to auto, the IIS takes the error page again and no more ColdFusion errors showed.

Anyone has a solution?  I did some research and "suspect" that the JWildcardhandler maybe the problem, but I couldn't find a solution to this.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Think good idea would be to show the samples of your web.config.

Comment: Is your default document in IIS set to be index.cfm?  If it is on index.aspx or index.htm then it could be trying to pass the 404 error through without there being a 404 error on ColdFusion.

Comment: In the IIS properties for the site, look at what the 404 error handler page is set to.

Comment: I tried setting my default document in IIS to index.cfm, removing every other default document, and it still appears to ignore it, returning a blank page. So frustrating. Why not just have a setting that allows the server to behave **exactly as it did** prior to IIS7?

Answer (score 22):

In case anyone is wondering this person's web config *probably* looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        ...
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In earlier version of IIS, if your custom script returned an error code, IIS ignored it and let it through. *But* you could also set it up to handle error status with custom scripts.

On my old server, if a given URL was a 404, IIS was set up to execut /404.cfm, which displayed an error page *and* returned a 404 status code using `<cfheader>`.

However, *now* if that script returns a 404 status code, the end result is IIS returns a server error rather than return the response with the 404 status code.

The only way to avoid that is by using `existingResponse="PassThrough"` and then using a site-wide "Template Not Found" template, set in CFAdmin.

Here's the interesting part. I have index.cfm set up as the default index, and the **only** default index, for my site.

If I go to `/about/`, and `/about/index.cfm` exists, then it renders the page, as if I had asked it for `/about/index.cfm`.
And if I go to `/about/index.cfm` and `/about/index.cfm` does *not* exist, it executes the site-wide 404 template.

***But*** if I go to `/about/` and `/about/` does not exist as an URL, it does *not* attempt to load `/about/index.cfm` and thus trigger the site-wide 404 template. Instead, it renders a blank page!

As far as I can tell, **there is no workable solution to this problem**. It looks like only people writing in .Net can resolve this issue, as they can put a flag in the Response that they generate that literally tells IIS "Ignore the status code". I think that Microsoft simply isn't interested in supporting alternate web application.

Basically, this is the solution: 
**get rid of `existingResponse="PassThrough"` and return the wrong status codes**.

Anything else is going to be too hard to implement. Note that this does not work if you are making a RESTful app or API. In which case, you must create a virtual directory just for that, for which you can assign a custom web.config file which *does* use `existingResponse="PassThrough"`. But if you need to be able to allow custom error handling and custom 404 handling, you are effectively screwed.

The good news is, apart from API and Ajax, the only other time someone will care about what the status code actually is will be when they're looking at your headers anyway, in which case they will see you're running IIS and just feel sorry for you.

Comment: gosh this sucks.  Any Update? Thx!

Comment: I've gotten it to work sometimes for 404s but not for any other status code. But it's never really consistent.

Comment: We've got a CMS and all requests go to the root/index.cfm page. That pages processes the URL and loads templates based on that. (Rewrite rules turn the url into a query string). I load custom headers when I can't find the page in my DB (404). However, when the url is root/page.cfm Fetch as Google says 404 as does Firebug/Chrome. But when the url is root/page/ Fetch as Google says its a 301 to itself but Firebug/Chrome still tell me 404 correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14368274/1229594 Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice work... I'm glad you got it working! I'm not going to dive into this because I have a feeling that a fix is days away. We'll see!

Comment: I came here with the same issue, but the fix for me was to ADD the "httpErrors" line to web.config.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping the passthrough in place, you could use a rewrite to handle the blank page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.cfm [NC,L,NS]
```

The rewrite basically means - if file and directory do not exist, redirect to "404.cfm. Also include a 404 cfheader on the 404.cfm page.

Comment: I modified the RewriteRule as follows in order to simulate the URL format that IIS uses when calling the 404 handler (which include the query string "?404;http://original-404-url")  
  
    `RewriteRule .* /error_404.cfm\?404;http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$&\?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,NS]`