# Can't get IIS 7/Coldfusion to deliver 404

Tags: iis, iis-7, coldfusion, http-status-code-404, coldfusion-10

So... we have a custom CMS. We have a rewrite rule that any page request (when a file doesn't exist) goes to the root/index.cfm file. There we search our DB for the page in question. If the page exists, we serve up the correct template,etc. If the page doesn't exist I want to server up a 404 page. Now I "think" I cannot do this in IIS since I need to handle the request in CF, so it has to get through. The file will always exist. When the page doesn't exist I've tried using `<cfheader statusCode="404" >` and then include some html, it puts `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` at the top of the page before my html. In order to get it to display the page I had to remove the 404 status code handler from IIS.

In addition when I fetch as Google, it get's a 301. However when I view response headers in Firefox I get.

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 21:31:42 GMT
404 Not Found
```

I've tried a combination of redirecting and all sorts of things. I open to letting IIS handle the 404, if there is a way, but I cannot figure out how to get Coldfusion to correctly deliver a 404 so Google gets it right. Webmaster tools gets mad at me because I am delivering "Soft 404s" before this point, so I am trying to fix that.

I've also tried setting `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` whatever the hell that does, but didn't work either. I've been looking up other threads trying to figure this out and just can't.

EDIT: Looking further into this, viewing the header info in both Firebug & Chrome I clearly see the headers say 404. Why would Fetch as Bing and Fetch as Google say differently?

I tested the fact that if I add .cfm to the URLs, it Fetch as Google will deliver see 404. However without the .cfm, it thinks it's 301. Firebug sees both as 404. This seems like a Google issue.

**ANSWER Kind of:**

So I was doing more testing this morning (Right after I added a bounty actually), and I noticed in webmaster tools, Google correctly noted one of my pages as a 404. So I started looking into it. I have an "Add Trailing Slash Rule". Google notices `domain.com/page` as a 301 (Correct I guess) to `domain.com/page/`. But it does notice `domain.com/page/` as a 404. I think using the trailing slash rule as I have it is the right way, however, should I be doing something different, or is using the redirect with the slash the "correct" way of doing things, even though Google wants to ding me for it sometimes.

Comment: Are you sending the `statustext` with your `cfheader`?  Should be like this `<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found" />`.  This is how I do it and it works (in CF9).

Comment: I've added that yes. I see the headers in Firebug. However when the URL doesn't have a .cfm on it, Google sees it as a 301 to itself even when Firebug sees it as a 404. So I'll get soft 404 errors when I don't want them.

Comment: Are you using a URL rewrite rule or something similar for when a request does not have the .cfm file specified?  IIS rewrite, .htaccess, etc.

Comment: IIS rewrite. However all requests after domain.com go to `domain.com/index.cfm.` Example `domian.com/test/page/` and `domain.com/test/page.cfm` both route correctly to `domain.com/index.cfm`. Both are processed the same and both output the same in Firebug/Chrome. Headers say 404. Its Fetch as Google that think `domain.com/test/page/` is a 301 and `test/page.cfm` is a 404. I don't think the issue is with IIS. I make everything after the .com a query_string.

Comment: In your ColdFusion administrator do you have the option for `Enable HTTP Status Codes` turned on or off?

Comment: Didn't know this was an option, but it was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I follow the specifics of your approach, so I will give you a few things that you need to look at in order to get this approach working well (or at least what has worked best for me).

Under "Error Pages", make sure that your 404 error page is set to "Execute a URL on this site" ( I generally set mine to something like "/404.cfm"). This will make sure that your ColdFusion page is called correctly for 404 pages (it sounds like you have this working correctly).

Under "Handler Mappings", double-click on the handler for ".cfm". Then click the "Request Restrictions..." button. It should open to the "mappings" tab. The "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to:" checkbox should NOT be checked.

This can really trip up this sort of operation because it means that IIS won't invoke ColdFusion if the file doesn't exist. This shouldn't be an issue if your 404 is set up correctly, but still something to look into.

While you are in the "Handler Mapping" section, look for the IsapiModule with a path of "*". Mine is always set to ColdFusion - not sure if that makes a difference or not.

The other thing to look at is the "Default Document" setting. Keep in mind that this could impact you when forwarding to a folder.

You might also look at your rewrite rule again and make sure it isn't adding slashes where one already exists.

Comment: All page requests get sent to index.cfm, as they should. There are not "pages" on my website. I take all of the URL after the root, search for a matching page in my database and display that page if it exists. If not, I have to display a 404 page. IIS will not be handling my 404's as there are no physical page files.