# 404 error custom page working for .cfm extension but not for .html?

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, web-config

I am trying to redirect invalid pages to a custom 404 error page.

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

This is my web.config configuration code.

It is working for **www.abcxyz.com/invalid.cfm** but not for **www.abcxyz.com/invalid.html** and **www.abcxyz.com/invalid/** .

It is showing:
The connection was reset page.

Comment: What are you using for your web server? The ColdFusion server _normally_ only handles ColdFusion templates. The web server handles other file types (like .html). You also need to configure your web server's 404 handler to call your custom error page.

Comment: What is your ColdFusion version and web server ?

Comment: @Miguel-F Microsoft-IIS/7.5 is my web server and I already configure my web.config file but it didn't work. I put that Highlighted code.

Comment: @AnitKumar Web Server: IIS 7.5 and version is 10

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

If you want CF to handle errors you throw a 404 and point the app somewhere that is common (in that 'page' should be a cfheader with a status code of 404 and what we do is construct a template which supplies page content like an explanation to the user that they are indeed on a page that doesn't exist.

It gets set in the CF admin under settings and is an absolute path.

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/setting-cfml-based-missing-template.html

Then to further Anit's channel.  you need to tell your webserver like IIS to let your application deal with 404s.

For example if you have IIS then you need to do something like this in the web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[And you can find that SO conversation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968018/coldfusion-error-and-iis7-5-error-pages)

I hope this gets you on the right track...Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom error pages? The "**Edit Feature Settings**" under Error Pages in IIS for 404, should have **"Execute URL"** pointing to your 404.cfm

You may like to visit https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3488063